# How to take good pictures when you are at the right place at the wrong time?

Tags: tips

When traveling, I am usually at the place after sunrise and before sunset. I admit that if I am more passionate about photography, I will plan to be at a place at the right time for photography. But, it is not practical for me.

What accessories and techniques can help me make the best out of this situation?

Comment: This isn't really a great question, and "a good photographer will find things to shoot where and when he is" isn't really a great answer.

Comment: I don't think this is worth a community wiki either, better to ask specific questions for specific circumstances

Comment: Please vote down if you don't like the question.

Comment: @publicRavi I don't vote down unless absolutely necessary. You should revise the question based on the comments or wait for it to be resolved if you feel it is good enough. See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask specifically 'If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.'

Comment: @ClaraOnager Point taken. I will revise the question.

Comment: When you say "... after sunrise and before sunset ..." you mean "sometmie during the daytime.". Yes? How is that "the rong time". What are you wanting to see or photograph that you cannot because of the time you arrive?

Answer (score 6):

Being there are the right time makes a huge difference. Depending on how you travel, this can be rather difficult. General tours and cruises particularly tend to go places at the worst time of the day. Some areas like parks and natural wonders have opening hours which are very restrictive as well. The main trick in those situations is not much of a trick actually: **Just shoot what works.**

**The main difficulty when the sun is high is excessive dynamic range.** So the easiest is to find a way to frame elements which do not differ so much in brightness. Say you are visiting an imposing monument. Take a shot of the whole thing is going to work out poorly but instead focus on details such as carvings, doors, etc.

Then there is the *if you cant beat them, join them* approach. Take that imposing monument for example and **find angles where it has an interesting contour**. If you shoot there with some negative exposure compensation, you can get an interesting silhouette.

The last way is to **capture all that dynamic range using a set of bracketed exposures**. You can merge the set using Exposure Fusion or HDR. You really should be using a tripod for this and make sure there are no moving subjects in your frame. You mileage will vary greatly here and will generally not give the best results anyway.

Comment: Someone needs to put a lock on Itai's usage of bold :) Good answer though!

Comment: I am totally in favor of this use of bold. But there's a lovely meta-discussion on that [right over here on Meta](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2007/markdown-is-a-loverly-thing-but-can-we-agree-to-rein-it-in-a-little)

Answer (score 1):

shooting in B&W can sometimes *save* the shot.
That way you actually reduce the effect of poor lighting conditions and concentrate on texture, patterns, atmosphere, etc.

Nothing stopping you also from shooting in colour and then boost saturation to make some really unusual pictures.